# Java - How to avoid creation of setter only for a particular class needs?

Tags: java, oop

I am using Hibernate and currently using the setter to set the relation to parent in children at creation time (to avoid doing this manually for both sides). How I can avoid use of setter or avoid expose it to the rest of classes and get the same behaviour. Is it ok to use reflection? This is the code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST_GROUP")
@Getter
public class TestGroupEntity extends AuditedEntity{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner", nullable = false)
    protected UserEntity owner;

    @Column(name = "description")
    @Setter
    protected String description;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    protected Set<TestEntity> tests = Sets.newHashSet();

    public boolean addTest(TestEntity testEntity) {
        return tests.add(testEntity);
    }

    public boolean removeTest(TestEntity testEntity) {
        return tests.remove(testEntity);
    }

    public TestGroupEntity(UserEntity owner, Set<TestEntity> tests) {
        this.owner = owner;
        owner.setTestGroupEntity(this); ! how to avoid creation of setter
        this.tests = tests;
        tests.stream().forEach(t -> t.setTestGroupEntity(this));  ! how to avoid creation of setter
    }
}
```

This is the children class ( I would like to keep immutability on api level):

```
@MappedSuperclass
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestEntity extends AuditedEntity {

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    protected String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    protected String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "test_group", nullable = false)
    protected TestGroupEntity testGroupEntity;

    public void setTestGroupEntity(TestGroupEntity testGroupEntity) {
        this.testGroupEntity = testGroupEntity;
    }
}
```

Edit: I think commented sections of code was not visible. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How I can avoid use of setter or avoid expose it to the rest of
>   classes and get the same behaviour. Is it ok to use reflection?

Of course you can for example reduce visibility of `public setter`s to a visibility less wide than `public` in order that client classes of your entities cannot use them. 
Which is in your case the real problem since accessing any data from inside the object is possible in anyway

From [hibernate doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/mappingGuide/en-US/html_single/)  :

> Attributes (whether fields or getters/setters) need not be declared
>   public. Hibernate can deal with attributes declared with public,
>   protected, package or private visibility. Again, if wanting to use
>   runtime proxy generation for lazy loading the visibility for the
>   getter/setter should be at least package visibility.

So, try to use `private setter` for desired field. It should address your problem.

---

**Update After comment**

You have several workarounds to address your problem :

- using reflection (your basic idea).
  Drawback : it brings a little complexity, not a full check at compile-time and at last, someone who sees your code could wonder why you used that...
  It is the same thing for any concepts which relies on reflection such as AOP.
- declaring these `setters` with `package-private` level and put the 3 classes in the same `package`.
   Drawback :  the used package.
- creating `public` init `methods` which raises an exception if it used more than once for a same object.  In this way, you guarantee the coherence of the object if bad used. 
   Drawback :  method which should not be used by clients is still provided to clients.

Unfortunately, you have not a perfect solution since Java visibility mechanisms cannot provide a ready-to-use solution for what you are looking for.
Personally, I prefer reflection or init method solutions.

Personally, I noticed that in based-class languages as Java, a good developer has often the reflex to over- protect accessibility of objects/methods. In fact, in many cases, it is not needed because it will not break the application or data integrity.

Here an example with init method :

```
 public TestGroupEntity(UserEntity owner, Set<TestEntity> tests) {
        this.owner = owner;
        owner.constructInit(this); 
        this.tests = tests;
        tests.stream().forEach(t -> t.constructInit(this));  
    }

public class UserEntity {

    private TestGroupEntity testGroupEntity;

    public void constructInit(TestGroupEntity testGroupEntity) {
      if (this.testGroupEntity != null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("forbidden");
      }
      this.testGroupEntity=testGroupEntity;
    }

}
```

Comment: How possible is to reduce the visibility of making setter private in contained object and use this setter in aggregator ? I need workaround or different pattern to make this setter visable only for this particular aggregator class.

Comment: From which aggregator class ? In your code I don't see any call of setters. Please provide all data required to understand your problem.

Comment: I have uncommented this section:         tests.stream().forEach(t -> t.setTestGroupEntity(this));  ! how to avoid creation of setter

Comment: Thank You for the answer

Comment: No problem :) So what do you will do ? :)

Comment: I will use just setter throwing IllegalArgumentException when this field is setted as you show and with @Deprecated annotation.

Comment: To limit usage of the class by external class, you could also make the method throws a custom checked exception as `UnavaibleOperationException` rather than  a `RuntimeException` exception which must not necessary be handled by clients. In this way, any client should explicitly handle know and will think twice before calling the operation.

Comment: @davidxxx hey david. I have a question related to oops [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938047/minimize-the-code-duplication-in-a-class) and wanted to see how we can minimize the duplication. Wanted to see if you can help out?

Comment: @John Answer brought by Alexander Kulyakhtin is fine. I think that you should follow the advice

Comment: ohkk sure.. just wanted to make sure if there is anything else I need to take care.

Answer (score 0):

Make a constructor in your parent class and call it from child.

Here is the parent constructor looks like

```
public AuditedEntity(UserEntity owner, Set<TestEntity> tests){
  this.owner = owner;
  this.tests = tests;
}
```

And change your child constructor like

```
public TestGroupEntity(UserEntity owner, Set<TestEntity> tests) {
   super(owner,tests);

}
```

Comment: Please provide both parent and child classes . @Milso

Comment: TestGroupEntity and TestEntity are two child classes, AuditedEntity is your parent . Right?Provide your parent class too. I think you want to make your class immutable , to make your class immutable you can make constructor and pass the values at the object creation time.

Comment: I would like to set bidirectional relation: TestGroupEntity contains TestEntities (TestGroupEntity is parent and TestEntities are children). To set this bidirectional relation currently I am setting the parent for every one of my TestEntities passed to constructor throught children's setter (t.setTestGroupEntity(this)). I would like to avoid this setter because this method is only for this class purpose and I think should't be available for rest of classes.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the post. Maybe commented sections were unvisible.

Comment: Did you test my answer ?

Comment: No because that's beside the question.