# minimize the code duplication in a class?

Tags: java, oop, optimization, design-patterns

I am using below class to send data to our messaging queue by using socket either in a synchronous way or asynchronous way as shown below.

As of now I am duplicating lot of code in my below class. I have 5 method below which is use to send data either synchronously or asynchronously and I believe there might be better way to rewrite those method.

```
public class SendRecord {
  private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
  private final Cache<Long, PendingMessage> cache =
      CacheBuilder
          .newBuilder()
          .maximumSize(2000000)
          .concurrencyLevel(100).build();

  private static class Holder {
    private static final SendRecord INSTANCE = new SendRecord();
  }

  public static SendRecord getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private SendRecord() {
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        handleRetry();
      }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }  

  private void handleRetry() {
    List<PendingMessage> messages = new ArrayList<>(cache.asMap().values());
    for (PendingMessage message : messages) {
      if (message.hasExpired()) {
        if (message.shouldRetry()) {
          message.markResent();
          doSendAsync(message);
        } else {
          cache.invalidate(message.getAddress());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // called by multiple threads concurrently
  public boolean sendAsync(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords) {
    PendingMessage m = new PendingMessage(address, encodedRecords, true);
    cache.put(address, m);
    return doSendAsync(m);
  }

  // called by above method and also by handleRetry method
  private boolean doSendAsync(final PendingMessage pendingMessage) {
    Optional<SocketHolder> liveSocket = SocketManager.getInstance().getNextSocket();
    ZMsg msg = new ZMsg();
    msg.add(pendingMessage.getEncodedRecords());
    try {
      // this returns instantly
      return msg.send(liveSocket.get().getSocket());
    } finally {
      msg.destroy();
    }
  }

  // called by send method below
  private boolean doSendAsync(final PendingMessage pendingMessage, final Socket socket) {
    ZMsg msg = new ZMsg();
    msg.add(pendingMessage.getEncodedRecords());
    try {
      // this returns instantly
      return msg.send(socket);
    } finally {
      msg.destroy();
    }
  }

  // called by multiple threads to send data synchronously without passing socket
  public boolean send(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords) {
    PendingMessage m = new PendingMessage(address, encodedRecords, false);
    cache.put(address, m);
    try {
      if (doSendAsync(m)) {
        return m.waitForAck();
      }
      return false;
    } finally {
      cache.invalidate(address);
    }
  }

  // called by a threads to send data synchronously but with socket as the parameter
  public boolean send(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords, final Socket socket) {
    PendingMessage m = new PendingMessage(address, encodedRecords, false);
    cache.put(address, m);
    try {
      if (doSendAsync(m, socket)) {
        return m.waitForAck();
      }
      return false;
    } finally {
      cache.invalidate(address);
    }
  }

  public void handleAckReceived(final long address) {
    PendingMessage record = cache.getIfPresent(address);
    if (record != null) {
      record.ackReceived();
      cache.invalidate(address);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any better way to rewrite those above methods?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requests to review working code belong to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, you could use the "Extract Method" refactoring a couple of times.

This code repeats:

```
ZMsg msg = new ZMsg();
    msg.add(pendingMessage.getEncodedRecords());
    try {
      // this returns instantly
      return msg.send(liveSocket.get().getSocket());
    } finally {
      msg.destroy();
    }
```

so make something like private void sendMsg() out of it.
This code also repeats

```
PendingMessage m = new PendingMessage(address, encodedRecords, false);
    cache.put(address, m);
    try {
      if (doSendAsync(m, socket)) {
        return m.waitForAck();
      }
      return false;
    } finally {
      cache.invalidate(address);
    }
```

so make another method out of it.

In general, there's a classic and excellent book on refactoring [https://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Improving-Design-Existing-Code/dp/0201485672](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672)

Answer (score -1):

there are two ways of reducing java code.

1. Switch to Kotlin.

You can use single kotlin files in a java project or convert the whole project.
Eclipse and Android Studio can convert a whole project from Java to Kotlin.

You can use Java classes inside Kotlin classes and vice versa.

In Kotlin you can use default arguments.

```
fun doSendAsync(pendingMessage: PendingMessage, socket: Socket = SocketManager.getInstance().getNextSocket().get().getSocket())
```

If a socket is passed, it will be used. Otherwise SocketManager.getInstance().getNextSocket().get().getSocket() will be used.

This would be your method declaration for

```
  private boolean doSendAsync(final PendingMessage pendingMessage, final Socket socket)
```

and

```
  private boolean doSendAsync(final PendingMessage pendingMessage)
```

---

2. Send default attributes to the more complex method.

If you want to use Java, do the following.

```
 private boolean doSendAsync(final PendingMessage pendingMessage) {
    return doSendAsync(pendingMessage), SocketManager.getInstance().getNextSocket().get().getSocket());
 }
```